# Gif loops infinitely in mobile even though set to loop once

Tags: jquery, html, css, gif, animated-gif

I have a gif that I have, and is set via photoshops timeline to loop only once.
In desktop the gif runs perfectly and as expected - only once, and then stops at the last frame just like I want it to.

But, when im testing in mobile, when I open my site and check the gif, it runs again and again and never stops.
I did nothing special, just a simple

What am I missing, and how can I get the same result in mobile as well?

Answer (score 0):

Some photo viewers software repeat any GIF image without stopping. Like irfanview(even in desktop). You can open with web browser. It will show correct animation loop.

Can you send the GIF URL?

Comment: yes, there you go: http://mashcantica.co.il/wp-content/themes/mashkantika/images/House_gif.gif , I have opened it in chrome on mobile, and it just loops again and again. Notice the image itself is white so it might be a little hard to see

Comment: Can you set at least 0.1 seconds not 0 second in each frame on Photoshop timeline?

Comment: I did, there you go: http://mashcantica.co.il/wp-content/themes/mashkantika/images/House_gif2.gif , but that doesnt seem to make anything change.